# Setting condition for the combo box in a user form

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, userform

Hi currently i have a user form that look like this for adding of new projects:
[image]

In the combo box, the user may select "Big Project", "Medium Project" and "Small Project" sizes. Each project sizes consist of a specific range in the sheet shown below:
[image]

The user would add in the project details into the userform and select the combobox drop down list for the project sizes and the new project details will be added into the empty rows found under each specific project sizes. Unfortunately i am not sure how to do it do in term of ranging each project sizes in the combo box drop down list so that when the user already selected the project sizes and click on the add command button, the new project details will be added to the new row found on the selected project sizes. in Addition, i have some problem with the  command add button that says 'Application-defined or object-defined error' on the codes shown below and not sure if the codes will help to add into the lastrow found on the specific project sizes. I am pretty lost in what to do for both the combobox and command add button.

```
Private Sub CommandAddButton1_Click()

lastrow = Sheets("Program status summary").Range("B").End(xlDown).Row 'shows the above mention error'

    Cells(lastrow + 1, "B").Value = TextBoxProjCode.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "C").Value = TextBoxProjName.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "D").Value = TextBoxSector.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "E").Value = TextBoxObjective.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "H").Value = TextBoxProjSponsor.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "G").Value = TextBoxProjSponsorNew.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "F").Value = TextBoxProjM.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "T").Value = TextBoxRegulatory.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "N").Value = TextBoxRiskLvl.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "M").Value = TextBoxDatePar.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "J").Value = TextBoxCostPar.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "O").Value = TextBoxAffectCust.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "Q").Value = TextBoxCustNonRetail.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "P").Value = TextBoxCustRetail.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "S").Value = TextBoxOutsourcingImp.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "R").Value = TextBoxKeyStatus.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "K").Value = TextBoxSchStart.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "L").Value = TextBoxSchEnd.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "V").Value = TextBoxRagSchedule.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "U").Value = TextBoxRagFinancial.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "W").Value = TextBoxRagBenefit.Text
    Cells(lastrow + 1, "I").Value = TextBoxCost.Text

Unload AddProject

End Sub
```

I really hope anyone could assist me with the combo box of the project sizes in inserting the range for each project sizes and the error on the add command button. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: `Range("B")` is not a valid range

Comment: @nabilah, is it guaranteed that there is always place (empty row) available to insert a project inside its category?

Comment: Hi, yes there is always an empty row between each project sizes as seen in the image above unless i could find a code that would allow me to insert new rows and at the same time insert the new project details into the new inserted rows into the category @A.S.H

Comment: Ok, then I will give you a solution in a few time :)

Comment: I suggest you put your data in separate sheets each named with the project size. That way it will be easier to handle addition or even deletion and updating.

Comment: Alright I think that would be a good idea! Thank you! :) but i asked my supervisor regarding this but he still wants to do it all the project sizes in one sheet @L42

Comment: `lastrow = Sheets("Program status summary").cells(rows.count,"B").end(xlup).row` to find last row. you should also have `dim lastrow as long` in the beginning

Comment: You may have to attach a sample workbook to your google drive account and supply the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub CommandAddButton1_Click()
  Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Program status summary")
  Dim emptyRow As Integer: emptyRow = 1 + sh.UsedRange.Find(ComboBoxProjSizes.Text).End(xlDown).row

  With sh
    .Cells(emptyRow, "A").Value = 1 + Application.Max(.Columns(1)) ' to generate a new identifier in column 1

    .Cells(emptyRow, "B").Value = TextBoxProjCode.Text
    .Cells(emptyRow, "C").Value = TextBoxProjName.Text
    .Cells(emptyRow, "D").Value = TextBoxSector.Text
    .Cells(emptyRow, "E").Value = TextBoxObjective.Text
    .Cells(emptyRow, "H").Value = TextBoxProjSponsor.Text
    .Cells(emptyRow, "G").Value = TextBoxProjSponsorNew.Text
    .Cells(emptyRow, "F").Value = TextBoxProjM.Text
    .Cells(emptyRow, "T").Value = TextBoxRegulatory.Text
    .Cells(emptyRow, "N").Value = TextBoxRiskLvl.Text
    .Cells(emptyRow, "M").Value = TextBoxDatePar.Text
    .Cells(emptyRow, "J").Value = TextBoxCostPar.Text
    .Cells(emptyRow, "O").Value = TextBoxAffectCust.Text
    .Cells(emptyRow, "Q").Value = TextBoxCustNonRetail.Text
    .Cells(emptyRow, "P").Value = TextBoxCustRetail.Text
    .Cells(emptyRow, "S").Value = TextBoxOutsourcingImp.Text
    .Cells(emptyRow, "R").Value = TextBoxKeyStatus.Text
    .Cells(emptyRow, "K").Value = TextBoxSchStart.Text
    .Cells(emptyRow, "L").Value = TextBoxSchEnd.Text
    .Cells(emptyRow, "V").Value = TextBoxRagSchedule.Text
    .Cells(emptyRow, "U").Value = TextBoxRagFinancial.Text
    .Cells(emptyRow, "W").Value = TextBoxRagBenefit.Text
    .Cells(emptyRow, "I").Value = TextBoxCost.Text
    .Rows(emptyRow+1).Insert
  End With
  Unload AddProject
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, i tried your code but it gave error on the line ': emptyRow = Sheets("Program status summary").FindEmptyRow(ComboBoxProjSizes.Text)' which says object does not support this property or method. In addition, i also not sure of how i should set the set of range for my combo box drop down list for each of my project sizes for the 'Private Sub ComboBoxProjSizes_Change()' is there any way i could produce the code with your help? @A.S.H

Comment: Hi @nabilah, please take the current version and copy/paste it as is and tell me if it works

Comment: Hi i tried the code u gave and it gave the error which i have mention above. It says "object does not support this property or method" on the line "emptyRow = Sheets("Program status summary").FindEmptyRow(ComboBoxProjSizes.Text)"

Comment: Also, the Project code is also know as project ID is to be in column B not A

Comment: yes I knew that, but in column A it seems there is some number NO which is very likely automatically generated. You can drop that. p.s: i am fixing the code, few minutes

Comment: @nabilah please try the edited version. I think the idea is there, and it worked with me excpet that i had to "simulate" some of the controls you have. BTW if you dont need to add anything in column A, you can drop that line of code

Comment: Ok sure thank you! Give me a  minute to try the codes you gave :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90396/discussion-between-a-s-h-and-nabilah).

Comment: Hi i tried the code but when i select the "Big project" in the combo box, the new project details actually overwrite one of the occupied rows in the big project category